# jQuery - remove wrapping tag, but maintain text position?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have a scrap of code like this:

`Lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit amet</span>, lorem ipsum dolor...`

I can select the span with jQuery and remove it from the DOM, but that removes the contained text as well. Is there a way, using jQuery, to remove the wrapping span while leaving the text in place? Is it possible to re-inject the text in it's original position, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$('span').contents().unwrap()`.

nb: `.unwrap()` removes the parent from an element (or text node), so you have to descend into the contents of the `<span>` to then unwrap them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to unwarp the content inside the span:

```
$("span").contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .unwrap() method. http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

```
$('span').contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Show / Hide dropdown option in IE browser, this is tested code

```
$("#PrimaryIndustry").find("select").children("option[value='" + selectedIndustry + "']").wrap('<span>').hide(); // use for hide option

$("#PrimaryIndustry").find("select").children("option[value='" + selectedIndustry + "']").unwrap('<span>').show(); // use for show option.
```